# BGE mouse over doesn't work. How to fix it?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

My Mouse Over sensor doesn't work when I try to use it for a cube, although it works very good when used for other objects.
First I wasn't sure if it maybe was due to the fact that I changed the Physics settings to "No Collision" in the physics tab, but after changing it back to "Static" it didn't work either. What can I do? Do you need the file?

Comment: ¿Could you provide your blend file? or images of your logic editor and maybe scripts that you are using, i just made a test following the steps that you describe and the Mouse over sensor work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the object can not be set to *No Collision*, *Occluder* and *Sensor* also do not work.

The mouse sensor will detect any static, dynamic, rigid body, soft body, and character objects.

To make testing easier enable the mouse pointer in the game.
[image: mouse cursor setting]

Then set up just a Mouse sensor, set to *Mouse Over*, and some actuator like Visibility, or End Object just to test the mouse interaction. Put that on the default cube.
[image: logic bricks]